# Hide Apps in the Windows Store

Tags: apps, store

So I know you can hide apps in the store: http://www.ghacks.net/2016/05/18/hide-windows-store-library-apps/ but, I am wondering what this actually does?

As far as I can tell if I hide an app

- it hides it in my library (*unless I hit show all*)
- it does not hide the app in the store (*if I search for it I can still find the app*)
- it does not stop linking to the app (*if I click a store link in edge, it still takes me to the app*)

Really I want to hide this app completely from the store. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't understand how the hiding works and I'd like to. I also want to hide inappropriate apps from work phones as I manage our companies phone systems.

Comment: You can press them for some time after that select hide app..